# Lao font Phetsarath OT

Tags: fonts

Fonts name: Phetsarath OT is edit on 10/20/2014 my county use this news font but in my Ubuntu is use Phetsarath OT old font 
Can you help me please change Font Phetsarath OT news People in Lao Use this Edit font and all my word 
you can go to new font to http://www.phetsarath.gov.la/download.php
an you see ຟອນເພັດຊະລາດ edit(10/06/2014)  this is new Fonts 
when i intall this font is not work

Answer (score 2):

I have uploaded a new version of the `fonts-lao` package to the development release:

[fonts-lao_0.0.20060226-9ubuntu1_all.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/294774770/fonts-lao_0.0.20060226-9ubuntu1_all.deb)

Just download and install that package to make use of Phetsarath OT from www.phetsarath.gov.la.

Thanks for pointing out that Ubuntu shipped an ancient version!

*Edit:*

To raise the precedence of Phetsarath OT you can try to add a configuration file along these lines:

```
$ cat ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-lao-preferred.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Phetsarath OT</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much now can i use new Font thank i love Ubuntu verry much 
'_' and how to change Font in My Folder because all lao People Use Phetsarath OT when i go to Text Entry i see Lao and Lao (Stea Proposed Standard Layout) But it not have Phetsarath OT i Wan to Phetsartath OT is Standard Keyboard Because on My Document and all People in lao Use Phetsarath OT my state use this font to all

Comment: @XayyasithKeohavong: Text entry is about typing, and if there exists a Phetsarath OT keyboard layout it would need to be added to xkb. That's something which must be done by a Lao developer who knows what such a layout looks like. One thing you can do is installing the `ibus-m17n` package, log out and log in again. That will add two IBus options for typing Lao. I can't tell if it would help, but you may want to give it a try. Otherwise I just edited my answer and proposed a configuration file which may increase the chances that Phetsarath OT is used for rendering Lao characters.