# Setting preferred fonts with .fonts.conf

Tags: 16.04, fonts, configuration

I'm working out a few kinks on my system regarding font conflicts and I've noticed that it can be fixed by setting preferred fonts. I tried the following in my `~/.fonts.conf` file:

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0"?>
>  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
>  <fontconfig>
>     <alias>
>         <family>fontawesome-webfont</family>
>         <prefer><family>FontAwesome Regular</family></prefer>
>     </alias>
>  </fontconfig>
> ```

This seems to match the formatting I found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration), but it still doesn't serve it's purpose.

When I run `fc-match -s FontAwesome`, FontAwesome comes up as:

> fontawesome-webfont.ttf: "FontAwesome" "Regular"

With this, I'm assuming that the family derives from `fontawesome-webfront.ttf` and the sub-family comes from `Regular`

I also made sure to run `sudo fc-cache -f -v` after every edit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `fontawesome-webfont` a correct family name?

Comment: I believe so. Isn't that what `fc-match` is supposed to output?

Comment: Well, what's shown to the left when you run `fc-match` is the file name. I'm not sure if those are necessarily valid family names. I have used similar config files sometimes and then used `sans-serif` as family name. See for instance [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/852984).